# JS querySelectorAll for elements of a specific grandparent unless their parent has a specific ID

Tags: javascript, queryselector

I'm trying to select `input[type="submit"]` elements that are descendants (not direct) of `article` elements with a `id` attr starting with `post-` (i.e. `article[id^="post-"]`) but not if they're also descendants of the `#custom-footer` element.

This returns both `input` elements from the code below.

```
document.querySelectorAll('article[id^="post-"] :not(#custom-footer) input[type="submit"]')
```

Same with this.

```
document.querySelectorAll(':not(#custom-footer) input[type="submit"]')
```

HTML:

```
<article id="post-2">

    <div> <!-- multiple nested divs -->
        <div>
            <input type="submit"> <!-- match me -->
        </div>
    </div>

    <div> <!-- multiple nested divs -->
        <div>
            <div id="custom-footer">
                <input type="submit"> <!-- DO NOT match me -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</article>
```

Comment: Make sure your spacing is correct. Can you include sample HTML?

Comment: How can we help with a selector if we can't see the relevant HTML?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl updated the post

Comment: @DavidThomas the post has been updated

Answer (score -1):

When you have a selector of the form `a :not(b) c`, it selects elements matching `c` which are *descendants* of elements not matching `b`, where the latter are descendants of elements matching `a`.

This will tend not to be useful, because there may be multiple nodes between `a` and `c`, and only one of them needs to match `:not(b)` for the element to be selected. This only requires at least one ancestor of `c` below `a` to not match `b` - i.e. it selects `c` if **not all** ancestors above `a` match `b` - probably not what you intended.

If you only want elements which are not *children* of elements matching `b`, write `a :not(b) > c` to use a child selector instead of a descendant selector. This requires **the parent** of `c` to not match `b`.

Alternatively, if `:not(b)` is really meant to apply to ancestors rather than just the parent, then this is not generally possible. The selector you want would be like `a c:not(b *)`, matching `c` with **no ancestors** below `a` matching `b`. However, the [CSS specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#negation) forbids descendant selectors in `:not()`, so this won't work. This means you cannot use `querySelectorAll` to select elements with **no ancestors** matching `b`. As a workaround, you could write a helper function to test whether an element has an ancestor matching `b`, and then use Array.filter to exclude elements which do.

Comment: Your first paragraph describes exactly what I want to do. Element B is a child (not direct) of Element A. Element C can be a child (not direct) of either. I want to select Element C that are children of Element A but not when they are children of Element B.

Comment: OK - I've added an extra paragraph to cover this case.

Comment: `article[id^="post-"] input[type="submit"]:not(#custom-footer *)` is what I have after following your last paragraph. It returns nothing. Console states `... is not a valid selector`

Comment: Ah, I've realised that the CSS spec actually forbids descendant selectors in `:not()`, so this is actually not possible. You will need a different solution.

Comment: Can you suggest a different solution? I don't understand what else I'm supposed to do

Comment: "As a workaround, you could write a helper function to test whether an element has an ancestor matching b, and then use Array.filter to exclude elements which do."

Answer (score -1):

OK, if you want to get the child inputs of articles, but exclude any under the `#custom-footer` element, you will need to implement some kind of "closest" function. You just go up the parent lineage and check the selectors and ignore any that match the one you do not want to include.

```js
/* Polyfill */
if (!Element.prototype.matches) {
  Element.prototype.matches =
    Element.prototype.matchesSelector ||
    Element.prototype.mozMatchesSelector ||
    Element.prototype.msMatchesSelector ||
    Element.prototype.oMatchesSelector ||
    Element.prototype.webkitMatchesSelector ||
    function(s) {
      var matches = (this.document || this.ownerDocument).querySelectorAll(s),
        i = matches.length;
      while (--i >= 0 && matches.item(i) !== this) {}
      return i > -1;
    };
}

let childSel = 'article[id^="post-"] input[type="submit"]';
let parentSel = 'article[id^="post-"]'; /* Optional */
let excludeParentSel = '#custom-footer';
let filteredButtons = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(childSel)).filter((b) => {
  return getClosest(b, parentSel) != null && getClosest(b, excludeParentSel) == null;
});

filteredButtons.forEach(btn => console.log(btn.className)); // Only 2

// See: https://gomakethings.com/how-to-get-the-closest-parent-element-with-a-matching-selector-using-vanilla-javascript/#browser-compatibility
function getClosest(elem, selector) {
  for (; elem && elem !== document; elem = elem.parentNode) {
    if (elem.matches(selector)) return elem;
  }
  return null;
};
```

```html
<article id="post-2">
  <input type="submit" class="btn-valid-1">
  <!-- match me -->
  <br />
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <input type="submit" class="btn-valid-2">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- match me -->
  <div id="custom-footer">
    <input type="submit" class="btn-invalid">
    <!-- DO NOT match me -->
  </div>
</article>
```

Comment: In this case the `#custom-footer` element is a descendant of the `article` element

Comment: @AllanThomas I responded to this before you provided HTML. I can update.

Comment: Great JS but the descendants aren't direct descendants. There's tons of nested divs in between the parent `article` element and the child `input` elements. This still returns all `input` elements

Comment: @AllanThomas You do understand, that you have yet to provide the example HTML for this case. You never mentioned, "There's tons of nested divs in between the parent `article` element and the child `input` elements" in your question.

Comment: `descendants (not direct)` is written in my Q but I can understand the confusion.